# Can high GPIOs sink current?

Tags: current-source, gpio

The DRV103 has an input, which sources a constant current. A Resistor is used to configure the parameter associated but it is also possible to apply a voltage, if it can sink that current (A few µA).

If I now were to connect a generic GPIO of a generic µC, with a lower supply voltage, to that pin and switch it high, what would happen?

Can the GPIO sink current while beeing turned high or does it not and the voltage rises until it breaks down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MOSFETs conduct in both directions so it would sink current* if a (small) current source was trying to pull it higher than Vdd. However that could have bad effects during startup when the output is floating so if it really exists a Schottky clamp might be good insurance.

It is not obvious which pin you are talking about on the [DRV103](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv103.pdf?ts=1641517194746)- if you are worried about the 10nA typical leakage on the input, that is not an issue.

* More accurately, it will conduct current to the Vdd pin on the MCU. The distinction can be important if the current approaches the total load on Vdd and the regulator supplying it cannot sink current.